# Duplicate rows with conditions pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

i've an issue with my dataframe.

My df is :

```
product      power                   brand
product_1    3 x 1500W               brand_A
product_2    2x1000W + 1x100W
product 3    1x1500W + 1x500W        brand_B
product 4    500W
```

I need to mulpliy each rows with number of product (deducted with power)

My df expected :

```
product      power               brand          new_product
product_1    1500W               brand_A        product_1_1
product_1    1500W               brand_A        product_1_2
product_1    1500W               brand_A        product_1_3
product_2    1000W                              product_2_1
product_2    1000W                              product_2_2
product_2    100W                               product_2_3
product 3    1500W               brand_B        product_3_1
product 3    500W                brand_B        product_3_2
product 4    500W                               product_4_1
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

I would do a string extract and merge, followed by some cleaning tasks:

```
df1 = (df.power.str.extractall('(\d+)\s?x\s?(\d+W)')
         .reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
      )

new_df = df.merge(df1[1].repeat(df1[0]), 
                  left_index=True, 
                  right_index=True,
                  how='outer')

# update the power column
new_df['power']= np.where(new_df[1].isna(), new_df['power'], new_df[1])

# drop the extra 1 column
new_df.drop(1, axis=1, inplace=True)

# new_product column
new_df['new_product'] = (new_df['product'] + '_' + 
                         new_df.groupby('product').cumcount().add(1).astype(str) )
```

Output:

```
     product  power    brand  new_product
0  product_1  1500W  brand_A  product_1_1
0  product_1  1500W  brand_A  product_1_2
0  product_1  1500W  brand_A  product_1_3
1  product_2  1000W     None  product_2_1
1  product_2  1000W     None  product_2_2
1  product_2   100W     None  product_2_3
2  product 3  1500W  brand_B  product 3_1
2  product 3   500W  brand_B  product 3_2
3  product 4   500W     None  product 4_1
```

Comment: I was on the same path, you beat me to it. :)  +1

Comment: @Quang Hoang, how i can do for cases when i don't have power value ?

Comment: @Toine_zg Change the regex part of the first line to df.power.str.extractall('(\d*?)\s?x?\s?(\d*W)'), it can additionally match e.g. ' W' or 'W'.

Answer (score 0):

@Quang Hoang is a more correct answer as it is implemented only with `pandas` methods. Anyway I leave one solution just using plain python:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

cols = ['product', 'power', 'brand']

data = [
  ['product_1', '3 x 1500W', 'brand_A'],
  ['product_2', '2x1000W + 1x100W', np.nan],
  ['product 3', '1x1500W + 1x500W', 'brand_B'],
  ['product 4', '500W', np.nan]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, data=data)
print(df)
```

Original data:

```
     product             power    brand
0  product_1         3 x 1500W  brand_A
1  product_2  2x1000W + 1x100W      NaN
2  product 3  1x1500W + 1x500W  brand_B
3  product 4              500W      NaN
```

#### Data wrangling

```
items = df.power.values.tolist()
brands = df.brand.values.tolist()

res = zip(items, brands)

new_data = []

for idx, aux in enumerate(res):
  item, brand = aux
  for idx2, power_model in enumerate(item.split('+')):
      res = power_model.strip().split('x')
      if len(res) == 2:
        units, val = res
      else:
        units = 1
        val = res[0]

      for _ in range(int(units)):
        new_data.append(
            [
              f'product_{idx + 1}', 
              val,
              brand,
              f'product_{idx + 1}_{idx2 + 1}'
            ]
        )

new_cols = ['product', 'power', 'brand', 'new_product']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=new_cols, data=new_data)

print(df2)
```

#### Result

```
     product   power    brand  new_product
0  product_1   1500W  brand_A  product_1_1
1  product_1   1500W  brand_A  product_1_1
2  product_1   1500W  brand_A  product_1_1
3  product_2   1000W      NaN  product_2_1
4  product_2   1000W      NaN  product_2_1
5  product_2    100W      NaN  product_2_2
6  product_3   1500W  brand_B  product_3_1
7  product_3    500W  brand_B  product_3_2
8  product_4    500W      NaN  product_4_1
```