# Transpose dataframe and extract informations on columns values

Tags: python, regex, pandas, transpose

I've a loop who created 4 dataframes*2 and I would like to transpose informations on an other one.

My dfs :

```
  productA
0 convecteurs à régulation mécanique
1 6
2 Brand_A
3 (1 x 500 + 3 x 1000 + 2 x 1500)

 productA
0 Convecteurs
1 3
2 Brand_B
3 1 x 500 + 2 x 1500

 productA
0 4
1 Brand_A
2 2x 1750 + 1 x 1260 + 1 x 2000

 productA
0 Convecteurs
1 3
2 Brand_B et Brand_C 
3 2 x 1500 + 1 x1000

 productB
0 1
1 Brand_A
2 3000 W

 productB
0 1
1 BrandD
2 1200 W

 productB
0 2
1 Brand_C 100 l 1200 W + BrandE 75 l 1500 W

 productB
0 1
1 Brand_C
2 1200 W
```

And I would like to transpose each to an other dataframe, like this :

```
new_product appareil                            brand   power
ProductA_1  convecteurs à régulation mécanique  Brand_A 500
ProductA_2  convecteurs à régulation mécanique  Brand_A 1000
ProductA_3  convecteurs à régulation mécanique  Brand_A 1000
ProductA_4  convecteurs à régulation mécanique  Brand_A 1000
ProductA_5  convecteurs à régulation mécanique  Brand_A 1500
ProductA_6  convecteurs à régulation mécanique  Brand_A 1500
ProductA_1  Convecteurs                         Brand_B 500
ProductA_2  Convecteurs                         Brand_B 1500
ProductA_3  Convecteurs                         Brand_B 1500
ProductA_1                                      Brand_A 1750
ProductA_2                                      Brand_A 1750
ProductA_3                                      Brand_A 1260
ProductA_4                                      Brand_A 2000
ProductA_5                                      Brand_B 1500
ProductA_6                                      Brand_B 1500
ProductA_7                                      Brand_C 1000
ECS_1                                           Brand_A 3000 W
ECS_1                                           BrandD  1200 W
ECS_1                                           Brand_C 1200W
ECS_2                                           BrandE  1500W
ECS_1       Brand_C 1200W
```

I don't find any good solution. Could you help me please ?
I think I need to you a regex expression ?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58187756/duplicate-rows-with-conditions-pandas-dataframe-python/58187875#58187875).

Comment: @Quang Hoang it's not the same question, i think the regex will be different